# Using AutoMapper on shared properties?

Tags: automapper

Can AutoMapper map shared properties?

**Entity**

```
public class Entity
{
    public static string SomeProperty {get; set;}
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: How are these properties shared?  They live in two unrelated classes  Also, is this the [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, I am using that Automapper, and I want to map the Entity to the View Model.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not used AutoMapper yet, I see no reason why you would not be able to achieve what you are looking for.  Based on the project's [documentation on Projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection), you can write a projector:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ViewModel>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeProperty));

// Perform mapping
ViewModel form = Mapper.Map<Entity, ViewModel>(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a code like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ViewModel>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.SomeProperty,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Entity.SomeProperty));
```